# Has anyone had problems assigning colours to font awesome using content using IOS 8.3?

Tags: html, ios, css

I am trying to replicate a bug on IOS 8.3 where I select a checkbox and the colour of my arrow is meant to be green but it is black instead.

Is this an IOS bug fix for this or is this something that it does not support?

here is my SASS/css:

```
input[type="checkbox"] + .field-label-replaced {
    &:before {
        background-color: $C-Bg-Field;
        border:           1px solid $C-Border; // Use px value to cope with field edges disappearing when zooming out
        box-sizing:       border-box;
        color:            $GIP-OxfamGreen;
        content:          '';
        height:           $D-FieldElement;
        text-align:       center;
        width:            $D-FieldElement;
    }
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .field-label-replaced {
    &:before {
        color:            $GIP-OxfamGreen;
        content:            '\2714';
    }
}
```

If you want to test it yourself I have a codepen account that shows the issue.

http://codepen.io/mattclaffey/pen/EjNwRw

Comment: Just tested it in IOS 8.2 were this was working, after updating to 8.3 the color does not change. It also does not help to change the pseudo element selector to `::before`.

Comment: What I found was the content code was to output a unicode character a tick. If I change that to random text then it shows green.

Answer (score 0):

Unicode characters are a bit interesting in that they are displayed differently by different things. Sometimes, they can also be displayed as a full-color symbol, rather than with a single tone, which means it can no longer be affected by CSS `color` rules.

Take this as an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/f4joLkmg/

In chrome and safari, the symbol is displayed as a purple umbrella with blue rain droplets, but in firefox, it is a single tone graphic, so it adopts the `red` style that was applied to it.

I don't have an IOS 8.3 device (as was mentioned in the comments to be where the issue was seen) so I can't test out how a checkmark symbol is displayed there, but I would assume that that OS version simply chooses to display that symbol with a specific color set, which means it can no longer be controlled by the text color.

So how do you get around it? Well, you mentioned [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) in your question title, but aren't actually using it here. If you've already got Font Awesome loaded up, you might as well just use that:

```
&:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    color: $GIP-OxfamGreen;
    content: '\f00c';
}
```

If you *don't* have Font Awesome already in use in your project.. well you still might want to consider using it, or something similar instead of unicode symbols. An actual icon font will always give you better results in terms of consistency, and most of the time the symbols look a little nicer as well.